# Program crashing with C++ DLL using OpenMP

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, dll, openmp

I have a program using OpenMP on C++ and I need it to port into Dll so I can call it from Python. It returns an array of double values, which calculated using a lot of for loops with openmp pragma. I was doubtful if it is going to work, so I started from a little test program that calculates Pi value in a loop with different precision values, then I would measure performance and ensure that OpenMP works properly that way. Plain (w/o Omp) implementation works fine from Python and C++, however Omp variant gives a runtime error in Python (`exception: access violation writing 0x000000000000A6C8`) and crashes without an error in C++. Also Omp variant works fine if it is not a Dll and just a regular executable. The Dll is made with a makefile. App that uses the Dll built into an executable with g++ with no flags (source code is in UnitMain.cpp). All the relevant code and a Makefile below (I didn't include some files and functions for brevity).

UPD: I tried Microsoft compiler and it works, also I tested a linux dynamic library on WSL/g++ and it also works. Looks like it is Windows gcc specific, I'll try another version of gcc (btw my current version is this):
`Thread model: posix gcc version 8.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project)`

**UnitFunctions.cpp**

```
#include "UnitFunctions.h"
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef long long int64_t;

double pi(int64_t n) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    int64_t sign = 1;
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {           
        sum += sign/(2.0*i+1.0);
        sign *= -1;
    }
    return 4.0*sum;
}

void calcPiOmp(double* arr, int N) {
    int64_t base = 10e5;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        arr[i] = pi(base+i);
    }
}
```

**UnitMain.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct DllHandle
{
  DllHandle(const char * const filename)
    : h(LoadLibrary(filename)) {}
  ~DllHandle() { if (h) FreeLibrary(h); }
  const HINSTANCE Get() const { return h; }

  private:
  HINSTANCE h;
};

int main()
{
  const DllHandle h("Functions.DLL");
  if (!h.Get())
  {
    MessageBox(0,"Could not load DLL","UnitCallDll",MB_OK);
    return 1;
  }

  typedef const void (*calcPiOmp_t) (double*, int);
  const auto calcPiOmp = reinterpret_cast<calcPiOmp_t>(GetProcAddress(h.Get(), "calcPiOmp"));
  double arr[80];
  calcPiOmp(arr, 80);
  cout << arr[0] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
all: UnitEntryPoint.o UnitFunctions.o
    g++ -m64 -fopenmp -s -o Functions.dll UnitEntryPoint.o UnitFunctions.o

UnitEntryPoint.o: UnitEntryPoint.cpp
    g++ -m64 -fopenmp -c UnitEntryPoint.cpp

UnitFunctions.o: UnitFunctions.cpp
    g++ -m64 -fopenmp -c UnitFunctions.cpp
```

**A Python script**

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes as ct

cpp_fun = ct.CDLL('./Functions.dll')  
cpp_fun.calcPiNaive.argtypes = [np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(), ct.c_int]
cpp_fun.calcPiOmp.argtypes = [np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(), ct.c_int]

arrOmp = np.zeros(N).astype('float64')
cpp_fun.calcPiOmp(arrOmp, N)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce with Microsoft compiler.  I had to `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)` the `calcPiOmp` function and remove `#include "UnitFunctions.h`, then compile with `cl /LD /W4 /openmp UnitFunctions.cpp`.  After defining `N` and removing the `calcPiNaive` reference, The result was an N-array filled with approximate pi.

Comment: Yup, looks like cl works fine. Dynamic library compiled for linux is also working. So it must be MinGW. Still gcc and Windows are preferred option for me because I need some bigger program make into dll and it would be too tedious to adapt it for Linux or Microsoft compiler. Anyway, thanks for the clue.